# Can I use Zinsser BIN over latex?

Tags: paint, sealer, shellac

My contractor inadvertently painted my plywood subfloor with latex wall paint instead of the Zinsser BIN shellac based primer I bought for it to seal in dog odor.

Now what do I do? Should I just wait a few days for the latex to totally dry and then paint over it with the BIN shellac sealant? Will the BIN still seal well since it will be going over paint instead of into the pores of the wood?

Or must I strip the paint before applying the Zinsser BIN?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely Zinsser over latex - just did it last week.  Now will the Zinsser after latex not cover up the smell as much.  I am not sure and not really sure anyone could say for sure but I would rather have it directly on the wood.  Latex will sit and Zinsser will work its way in more.

Comment: Tnx. Don't think I have much choice since sanding wouldn't really get the latex out of the pores. And he's not resistant. Will even replace wall paint at his expense. Prob best I can get overall.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the Contractor to contact [Rustoleum/Zinsser customer support](http://www.rustoleum.com/Rustoleum/pages/help-and-support)

If there is friction against your request, review the termination terms of the agreement with the Contractor.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, shellac-based finishes can be used between any two other finishes.  I refer you to "Understanding Wood Finishes" by Bob Flexner in which he makes this case.  He does not; however, cover the your case of shellac over latex paint because the context of his book is wood finishes that do not hide the look of the wood itself.